# Erlang shell freezes when printing a list

Tags: list, erlang

I am encountering a clueless problem here while I am trying to print out a list.
The program compiles fine but when I run it the compiler got stuck and will not process. Here is the code snippet:

```
print([]) -> []; 
print([H|T]) -> [H]++print([T]).
```

I split the list into head and tails because later I plan to implement more operations in it. So before that I just want to test if I can print a list as the user input.

I always declared the function from the start as `[print/1]`. Maybe I messed up somewhere else so please point it out.

Comment: this is infinite recursion

Comment: Should it stop when all elements in the list are extracted (reached[])? Because the second function should always end up to `[H] ++ print[]`?

Comment: First of all make your code compilable. Because now it is not.

Comment: Other than the fact that the `print[T]` at the end should be `print(T)`, there's nothing wrong with this code as shown. You can try something like it in the shell; running: `F = fun F([]) -> []; F([H|T]) -> [H]++F(T) end, F(lists:seq(1,5)).` will return `[1,2,3,4,5]` as expected. So you need to show us what your `print/1` function does before we can help you.

Comment: @SteveVinoski, it is not if code intended to be `print(T)` or `print([T])`.

Comment: @Lol4t0 like I said, if `print[T]` is changed to `print(T)`, it's fine. Did you try it? I did, and it works. If you instead change it to `print([T])` then that's a source of infinite recursion.

Comment: @SteveVinoski Yeah I messed up with the `[H] ++ print[T]` in my code. <br/> 
I actually wrote `print([H|T]) -> [H] ++ print([T])` in my code and after I removed the bracket in the middle ( `print(T)`) as you suggested, it runs fine.

Comment: @SteveVinoski but i am a little confused here also.. Because I think if the function starts with `print([])`, then based on pattern matching it should also have that `[]` bracket on the right side, otherwise how could `print(Xs)` gets matched back to `print([H|T])`?

Comment: If it automatically wraps up the elements (tails) into a list when it sees one, like the example above `print(Xs)`.. Then I guess it would make sense

Comment: I guess this only happens in erlang though... quite frustrating in learning ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you wrap the tail into a list before the recursive call.  Change `print([T])` to `print(T)`, and it will work.

Let's have a look at why this happens.  Consider the call `print([42])`, just one element to keep this simple.  Because of how lists work in Erlang, this could be written as `[42 | []]` and mean the same thing.

So we hit the clause `print([H | T])`, `H` being 42 and `T` being `[]`.  The recursive call is `print([T])`, which ends up being `print([[]])` (a list containing an empty list as its only element).

As we know, `[[]]` can be written as `[[] | []]`. Therefore, the recursive call once again goes into the `print([H | T])` clause, *not* the `print([])` clause as we expected. Now, `H` is `[]` and `T` is `[]`. The recursive call `print([T])` becomes `print([[]])`... and we have an infinite loop.

Comment: Aww, Thanks!! "`[[]]` can be written as `[ [] | [] ]`" just solved all mysteries here for me. Very illustrative answer!